# Where does mysqldump files go?

Tags: mysql, command-line, xampp, mariadb, command-line-arguments

I've read a post saying that I would have to use this command below, to dump my sql files

`$ mysqldump -u [uname] -p db_name > db_backup.sql`

However, my question is, I don't quite get where the db_backup.sql comes from. Am I suppose to create a file or is it being created as I enter any name for the backup sql?
Also, where can I find the backup.sql at?

More information: I am doing this on Mariadb/phpmyadmin on the xampp shell

Comment: I see that you have asked 3 questions on StackOverflow but you haven't marked any of the answers as accepted. I highly recommend you put closure to your questions by marking an answer of your choice as accepted. You can do that by clicking on the tick mark beside the answer that best meets your needs. That way, others with a similar question can see that your question was solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whichever directory you are in when you run that command will have db_backup.sql.

The statement:

`mysqldump -u user -p db_name` generates an output on the terminal screen, assuming you are SSH'ed into the server. Instead of the output written on the screen, you can redirect the output to a file.

To do that, you use  `> db_backup.sql` after the command.

If you are in directory /home/hyunjae/backups and run the command:

`$ mysqldump -u [uname] -p db_name > db_backup.sql`

You will see a new file created called db_backup.sql. If there's already a file with that name, it will be overwritten.

If you don't know what directory you are in, you can type `pwd` for present working directory.

Answer (score 1):

`db_backup.sql` is automatically generated by the `mysqldump`  command, and is located in the current directory (`.`) by default. If you need to specify a directory, you can directly specify `/path/to/target/db_backup.sql`.